# Magento does not recognizer secure attribute in email templates in checkout

Tags: image, email, magento, https

I have an email template for an email which will be send if a customer does the checkout in a Magento Enterprise version. Therefore I use the following code in the email template:

```
<img src="{{skin url='images/myImage.jpg' _secure=0 _area='frontend' _theme='myTheme'}}" />
```

There it says _secure=0 but I still get the image as https. The funny thing is if I resend the email in the backend under the orders item i get the image as http. Why do I get the image as https in the checkout then?

Comment: Did you clear cache before you checkout?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested your code above, but if it doesn't work for you they you can try

Creating a email_image.phtml in your template folder with the following code

```
$img = $this->getData('url');
echo '<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl($img, array('_secure'=>false)); ?>" />';
// and any other option you want to add above
```

Then in your static/email block

```
{{block type="core/template" url="images/myImage.jpg" template="path/to/file/email_image.phtml"}}
```